# PrometheusOperator Helm Chart: adding labels to default rules

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, alert

I need to add a label to all default rules that come with the Helm chart. I tried setting the label under `commonLabels` in the values file, to no avail. I also tried putting it as `external_labels` within the `defaultRules` stanza, again didn't do the trick. When I add the label to rules I define myself under `AdditionalAlerts`, it works fine. But I need it for all alerts.

I also added it under the "labels for default rules". The label got added to the metadata of each of the default rules, but I need it inside the spec of the rule, under the already existing label for "severity".

The end goal is to put the environment inside that label, e.g. TEST, STAGING and PRODUCTION. So if anyone has another way to accomplish this, by all means....

Comment: Hi @GID Have you tried the provided solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upgrade your values.yaml file for Prometheus with the necessary labels in the `additionalRuleLabels` section for `defaultRules`.

Below is an example based on the [values.yaml file from the Prometheus Monitoring Community](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L70):

```
defaultRules:
  ## Additional labels for PrometheusRule alerts
  additionalRuleLabels:
    additionalRuleLabel1: additinalRuleValue1
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Yes indeed, this worked, thanks.

Comment: @GID If my answer was useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it. If it answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Hi guys I used the same expecting those labels will appear in my redid service monitor , but it dint. Is there a way to add a label to all metrics in service monitor? @AndrewSkorkin